# table does not have min-height when set

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have a dynamic table where I populate with a fetch in my api, but I would like when there are few results to stay with the size of the table with the min-height, but I am not able to do that

I try to use the min-height: calc (100% - 60px)
to leave my table always with that minimum height, but when there are few dates the size does not obey the min-height:

[image]

css in js:

```css
/* Styles */

export const DepartamentMain=styled("div")` min-height: calc(100% - 60px) !important;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 20px;
`;
export const TableContent=styled("div")` box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(63 63 68 / 5%),
0 1px 2px 0 rgb(63 63 68 / 15%);
border-radius: 4px;
height: 100%;
`;
export const ResponsiveTable=styled("table")` width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
.paddingCheckbox {
  width: 48px;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px !important;
  color: #263238;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

tr {
  color: inherit;
  display: table-row;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tr-head {
  th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
    letter-spacing: 0.01071em;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    color: #263238;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.root {
  padding: 9px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  overflow: visible;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: transparent;
}

thead {
  visibility: visible;
  background: #fff;
}

tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #fff;
  td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.43;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
    letter-spacing: 0.01071em;
    vertical-align: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style={{ height: "100%", padding: 60 }} className="App">
  <DepartamentMain>
    <TableContent>
      <ResponsiveTable>
        <thead>
          <tr className="tr-head">
            <th className="paddingCheckbox">
              <span className="root">
                        <input name="select-all" value="ALL" />
                      </span>
            </th>
            <th>title 1</th>
            <th>tittle 2</th>
            <th>tittle 3</th>
            <th>tittle 4</th>
            <th>tittle 5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderDataList()}</tbody>
      </ResponsiveTable>
    </TableContent>
  </DepartamentMain>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//.       <thead>
//          <tr className="tr-head"> // try to change it to "table table-striped"
//            <th className="paddingCheckbox">
//              <span className="root">
//                        <input name="select-all" value="ALL" />
//                      </span>
//            </th>
//            <th>title 1</th> // try to change it to <th scope="col"></th to all 
//                                  of it.
//          <th>tittle 2</th>
//          <th>tittle 3</th>
//          <th>tittle 4</th>
//          <th>tittle 5</th>
//          </tr>
//        </thead>
```

you try to use col and change the tr to what I recommended for auto

Comment: what ? i dont understadn this.

Answer (score 0):

try to change it with my suggestion dude.

```
<tr className="tr-head"> -> <tr className="table table-striped">

<th>title 1</th> -> <th scope="col">title 1</th>
<th>title 2</th> -> <th scope="col">title 2</th>
<th>title 3</th> -> <th scope="col">title 3</th>
<th>title 4</th> -> <th scope="col">title 4</th>
<th>title 5</th> -> <th scope="col">title 5</th>
```